# How do I read this table?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Image: [image: Question]

I'm preparing for the Oxford TSA, and doing the previous papers as practice.

One question was a bit wacky for me though. Attached is the image of it. It talks about the mock examination results and the Actual GSCE results of English for a particular college.

The question is to state what percentage of pupils had the grades correctly predicted?

The table is the most perplexing thing for me though. how would you read that table :S?

Comment: too small brotha ... cannot see. Im bad at tables.

Comment: ohp, that's weird, one sec, will make sure it's bigger

Comment: Okay, image is at https://www.diigo.com/item/t/bM9%2FpcMU0tIbrBIcOT0R%2Blz2kinTwP8kqfibU6f8KI8%3D%0A

Answer (score 3):

There were $90+25+25+60=200$ total students who took both tests.  Of those, $90$ got A-C on the mock exam and again on the real exam.  The $25$ in the lower left got some other grade on the mock exam and A-C on the real exam.  The $25$ in the upper right got A-C on the mock exam and something else on the real one.  The $60$ in the lower right got other grades both times.  So $90+60=150$ got grades that matched.  $\frac {150}{200}=75\%$

Comment: Aha! This makes a LOT of sense! Thank you Ross!

Comment: It is unfortunate that they put $25$ in two different squares.  You could also note that adding the numbers in the first column shows that $115$ students got A-C on the actual exam, regardless of their performance on the mock exam.  Adding horizontally gives you the totals for each grade on the mock exam.

Answer (score 0):

The "25" in the top right box means that 25 students received grades A-C on the mock GCSE exam but received some other grade on the actual GCSE exam. To see this, look at the row heading for that box ("Mock GSCE Exams" / "Grades A-C") and the column heading for that box ("Actual GSCE Exams" / "Other Grades.")

The meaning of the other three numbers in boxes should be clear by analogy.

Comment: Hi Trevor, thanks for the response. I'm still not quite sure why though. Do you mind expounding on this a bit? I.e what are the total number of students here for example?

Comment: @StepanParunashvili If you have $n$ categories for a given thing (_e.g._ 2 categories for the mock exam scores: pass / no pass) and $m$ categories for another thing (_e.g._ 2 categories for the actual exam score: pass / no pass) then it's natural to represent the $nm$ total number of combinations in an $n \times m$ table.  The number in a box is the number of students who achieved that combination of scores.

Comment: Sorry Trevor, still a bit confused on this. Do you have any resource I can look at, that explains tables that look like this?

Comment: @StepanParunashvili I can't think of any such resource.  I'll try to clarify my answer a bit.